# How to use the nested iframe in html?

Tags: html

I am trying like this.But frame1 is visible. I can't show the frame2. The code is below,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="1000" height="1000" id="frame1" name="frame1">
  <iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://www.bing.com" id="frame2" name="frame2">
  </iframe></iframe></body></html>
```

Can any one please help me.

Comment: what you want to achieve? please do add some description...

Answer (score 8):

The child elements of an iframe are *alternative content* for use if frames are disabled or not supported.

Either make the child frame a sibling or move it to the document you load into the outside frame.

Comment: Hi.Sorry i can't understand. Can u please expalain this.

Comment: `<parent><child></child></parent>` and `<sibling></sibling><other_sibling></other_sibling>`

Comment: You do one of the two things I said. Move the inside iframe somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an iframe inside of and iframe you should do the following:

The link to access this page should have `?interframe=true` at the end of it.
e.g. `http://www.example.com/test.html?interframe=true`
You **shouldn't** add `?interframe=true` to the ends of `http://www.w3schools.com` and `http://www.bing.com` though.

To make it clear:
Let's say your homepage is `http://www.example.com` And the page that you need help with is `http://www.example.com/test`

The `<a>` tag in `http://www.example.com` that brings you to `http://www.example.com/test.html` should be `<a href="http://www.example.com/test.html?interframe=true">example text</a>`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can stack it up. But for nesting, you need to edit it.

Main page has iframe code pointing to page1. Page 1 has iframe code pointing to page2.

Don't nest them in one page. If you can't edit page 1 then stack them up.

MainPage.html

```
<DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<iframe src="page1.html" width="1000" height="1000" id="frame1" name="frame1"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<iframe width="200" height="200" src="page2.html" id="frame2" name="frame2"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

For stacking, see @Andri answer.

Comment: Balakumar for the stack u can see the code by @Andri. It will put two pages up and down. But if you really want a nested version, see my edit above.

Comment: This is the actual correct answer the actual question asked. The second iframe has to be nested in the first iframe from Page1.html. Putting them both in the main page wouldn't make any sense and stacking them isn't what the original question was about.

Answer (score 1):

try change your markup into the following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="1000" height="1000" id="frame1" name="frame1">
        </iframe>
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://www.bing.com" id="frame2" name="frame2">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this will work.But when i use like this i can't get the changed  frame1 source.It returns only the initial source(http://www.w3schools.com)..Is any solution?

Comment: have you tried changing the `src` attribute of the `frame1`? btw, what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: When i click the contents in frame1(), i can't get the correct url of the frame1("http://www.w3schools.com").....alert(document.getElementsById("frame1").src) will return only "http://www.w3schools.com" instead of the changed url. Any help?

Comment: maybe you could edit your question to reflect what you have done (including that code you write in your comment), and what you actually need...