# Issue with the Iframe display in row and column layout

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i am trying to show an html page from localhost below the chart but it doesn't show.
the chart is from tradingview widget that is being displayed, and now i am trying to show a custom page below that chart.

when i use iframe on a new html page it shows up and works fine but when i try and add it in the chart page it doesnt work

this is the code :

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 320px; 
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      $(document).on('change','.fx',function(){
       //var widget = changeFX(this.value);
        document.getElementById('content').src = "chart1.html?value="+this.value;
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = "block";
       });
</script>
<style>
  iframe{
    height:300;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
  }
</style> 
  </head>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:Tomato;">
   <select name="fx" class="fx">
    <option value="EURUSD">EURUSD</option>
    <option value="EURJPY">EURJPY</option>
    <option value="EURGBP">EURGBP</option>
    <option value="EURCAD">EURCAD</option>
    <option value="GBPUSD">GBPUSD</option>
    <option value="EURAUD">EURAUD</option>
    <option value="GBPJPY">GBPJPY</option>
    <option value="GBPCAD">GBPCAD</option>
    <option value="GBPAUD">GBPAUD</option>
    <option value="GBPCHF">GBPCHF</option>
</select>
<iframe src="chart1.html"   id="content" ></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<div class="column">
<iframe src="http://localhost:12321/index.html">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
</body>


  </body>
</html>
```

this is the output:
[image]

**can someone please point out What am i doing wrong? browser isnt showing any error either**

Thanks

Comment: What html does the arrow point to?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the arrow and the black rectangle is drawn manually in ms paint to show where i am trying to show the second i frame , this is the iframe that i am trying to place there -----------> <iframe src="http://localhost:12321/index.html">

Comment: You can't put an iframe inside an iframe, unless that page has an iframe inside it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018738/how-to-use-the-nested-iframe-in-html

Comment: okay so in other words i need to use iframe in the webpage that is being called via iframe on the main page ?

Comment: Is that your goal then? To put an iframe inside an iframe?

Comment: my end goal is to place 2 iframes vertically , and if its achieved via putting iframe inside of iframe then i dont mind,

Comment: Then does this answer your question? [How to use the nested iframe in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018738/how-to-use-the-nested-iframe-in-html)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for pointing out

Comment: If it doesn't help, please may you write a new question with an updated example?

Comment: it Does help , more precisely answer given by Martin Ivanovich in your mentioned post helps