# How can i access to iframe inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

```html
<iframe src="...">
    <iframe id="embedIframe" src="...">
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

I want to select an Iframe element with an Id of "embedIframe".

I tried `document.getElementById("embedIframe")` in the console window in developer tools.

But this returns a null value.

The strange thing is that if I directly click "embedIframe" in the Chrome Developer Tools element tab with the mouse, then return to the console window and type `document.getElementById("embedIframe")`, a normal value is output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxRnD.png

I'm using react.

React doesn't find `document.getElementById("embedIframe")` either.

How can i access to Iframe id "embedIframe" at once?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018738/how-to-use-the-nested-iframe-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a document containing an `iframe`, and *in the same document* you have another `iframe` as a child element of the first … then your HTML is invalid and you can't do that.

Children of iframes used to be alternative content to render if the browser didn't support iframes, but that has been phased out and iframes are no longer allowed children.

---

If you have an `iframe` with a `src` of `...` and then the document (from `...`) the is loaded into that iframe contains another iframe then `document.getElementById("embedIframe")` doesn't work because `embedIframe` isn't part of **that** document.

You need to get the iframe in the current document, then get the document belonging to that frame, and then search **that** document for the iframe you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var frame1 = top.document.getElementById("frame1");
var frame2 = frame1.contentWindow.document.getElementById("frame2");

frame2.document.getElementById("foo");
frame2.src = 'http://....';
```

Like this you can access the top iframe and then the embedded iframe also from within the embedded iframe. Give an id to frame1 so you can easily access it.

Your issue might be that you are inside the embedded iframe, so using document. from within that, to access the top doc, won't work.